# Individual probability

Tags: probability

This must be an easy question, but I can't get it.

> Suppose that 20 of 1000 people fail to pass exam. What would be probability that particular person will fail?

It's not 20/1000, right?

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Comment: "It's not 20/1000, right?" It would be good if you could explain some of your reasoning behind that statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you select that particular person. If they're selected at random, then indeed would be what you said it wasn't. (Consider the model where for each student I write their exam outcome *Pass* or *Fail* on a ball, put all the balls in a large bowl, mix well and and pull out a ball at random. What is the probability that I got a ball with "*Fail*" on it? Isn't that functionally identical to if I wrote their ID numbers on the balls instead and then looked up on student records whether they failed?)

If they're selected on some basis that would tend to make them not like someone selected at random (i.e. if your sampling method was repeated many times would relevant characteristics of those selected look different from the overall population?), it may differ a lot from 20/1000.

For example, if you just grab one of the first people to leave the exam room, then they're much more likely to be from the extremes (it's more likely that either they completed the exam very quickly and had nothing more to write, or they couldn't do anything on the paper at all). For example, if half of the 20 people who failed left early and 30 of the remaining 980 left early, then a random early leaver would have a 25% chance of failing.

Similarly, if you chose the oldest student, say, or one you happened to run into at the professor's office*, you would have non-random sampling and the probability might be much different from 20/1000.

* (students who approach the professor tend either to be very keen or having trouble, so it's probably a bit like the "early leaver" scenario)